# Why does showDatePicker require OK to be pressed?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, when using `showDatePicker`, why is the pressed date value not immediately accepted (without having to press OK)?

For example, if the widget initially opens at September 10th, 2019 and I want to select October 5th, 2019, I would expect switch the month to October and press 5 from the calendar display which would then automatically accept the date as October 5th, 2019 without having to press the OK button.

Is there a way to avoid needing to press the OK button?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really sound like a code issue, but I'll answer anyway.

The reasoning you have to press OK is mainly to optimize the user experience. Essentially, some people just have either bigger fingers or smaller screens, so they may bump the wrong date by mistake, and some may not even realize it if the dialog disappears after they select the date. Adding the OK button prevents users from running into this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Is there any way to avoid needing to press the OK button?

Comment: Not with the `showDatePicker` function. You'd have to create your own widget/function to achieve that functionality.